# Laravel - Adding Filter to Maatwebsite Excel Export

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I want to export only filtered data in view blade. I am using Laravel 5.8 and Maatwebsite 3.1 and PHP 7.

[image: excel_export]

Controller

```
    public function userresponseReport(Request $request)
{
    $data['title'] = 'User Response';

    $userresponses = DB::table('user_response as g')
    ->select(
       //DB::raw('DATE(g.created_at) as created_date'),
       DB::raw('g.created_at as created_date'),
       'g.msisdn', 
       'g.game_code', 
       'g.answer',
       'g.answer_code',
       'g.Amount_charged',
       'g.payment_ref',
       'g.status',
       'g.user_channel'                
  )               
 ->orderByRaw('g.created_at DESC'); 

    $start_date = $request->start_date;
    $end_date = $request->end_date; 

    $render=[];  
    if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date.' 00:00:00',$end_date.' 23:59:59']);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
    }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->where('created_at',$request->start_date);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
    }        
    if(isset($request->msisdn))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->where('msisdn','like','%'.$request->msisdn.'%');
        $render['msisdn']=$request->msisdn;
    }
    if(isset($request->game_code))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->where('game_code','like','%'.$request->game_code.'%');
        $render['game_code']=$request->game_code;
    }   
    if(isset($request->user_channel))
    {
        $userresponses=$userresponses->where('user_channel','like','%'.$request->user_channel.'%');
        $render['user_channel']=$request->user_channel;
    }      
    $userresponses= $userresponses->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    $userresponses= $userresponses->paginate(15);
    $userresponses= $userresponses->appends($render);
    $data['userresponses'] = $userresponses;

return view('report.userresponseReport',$data);        
}

public function exportuserresponse(Request $request) 
{       
    return Excel::download(new UserresponseExport($request), 'userresponse.xlsx');
}
```

I went through the documentation and applied this:

Export folder: UserresponseExport

```
class UserresponseExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{
use Exportable;

 protected $request;
public function __construct($request)
{
   $this->request = $request;
} 

public function collection()
{
    $userresponses = UserResponse::where('msisdn', 'like','%'.$this->request->msisdn)
            ->orWhere('game_code', 'like','%'.$this->request->game_code)
            ->orWhere('user_channel', 'like','%'.$this->request->user_channel)
            ->get();
    $output = [];

    foreach ($userresponses as $userresponse)
    {
      $output[] = [
        $userresponse->created_at,
          $userresponse->msisdn,
          $userresponse->game_code,
          $userresponse->answer,
          $userresponse->user_channel,
      ];
    }
    return collect($output);
}  


public function headings(): array
{
    return [
    'Date Created',
    'MSISDN',
    'game_code',
    'Answer',
    'Channel'
    ];
}
```

View

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    {{ Form::model(request(),['method'=>'get']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-2">
         {{ Form::text('msisdn',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'MSISDN']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
         {{ Form::text('game_code',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Game Code']) }}
    </div>   
    <div class="col-sm-2">
         {{ Form::text('user_channel',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Channel']) }}
    </div>          
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        {{ Form::date('start_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        {{ Form::date('end_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
    </div>          
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}
        <a href="{{ route('userresponseexport') }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel</a>
    </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

IThe export submit button is sending everything to Excel. How do I make it to send only the filtered data.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update your UserresponseExport, follow this formate,

```
 class UsersExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
    {
use Exportable;
 protected $request;
public function __construct($request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}
    public function collection()
    {
        $users = User::where('name', 'like','%'.$this->request->name)->get();
        $output = [];

        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
          $output[] = [
            $user->name,
          ];
        }
        return collect($output);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Name',
        ];
    }
    }
```

Make sure your query is corrct, check your query properly.

Comment: I did as you advised, but it still exported everything. See the update in my code. What else can I do?

Comment: I have updated my code, check now, and follow it, check your query outside, and make sure your query is working properly, try to use eloquent instead of raw sql

Comment: Where will I now put the filter. Because, if you check what I wrote I want the export to be based on filtered data in the view. For example based on selected game_code, user_channel,  Thanks

Comment: You have to filter in the collection function, check the example, I have update it

Comment: It still exports everything.   You can check my updated code.  .   From the code  public function userresponseReport(Request $request)   displays on view blade.    
public function exportuserresponse(Request $request)  sends to UserresponseExport.    Kindly assist

Comment: Don't use like, strict where `where('msisdn', $this->request->msisdn)` this way it will look for the exact value, do the same for other where clause as well

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196965/discussion-between-nazmul-abedin-and-user11352561).